# Absolute value of integral

Tags: calculus

I think it is well know that 
$$\left|\int f \right| \leq \int\left| f\right|$$
for some complex valued function $f$. This is normaly proven by writting it as an complex exponent, but can it be proven using only the fact that the integral is positive (i.e. positive functions give positive integrals)?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe prove more generally: if $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $\mathbb R^n$, then
$$
\left\|\int_X f(x)\,d\mu(x)\right\|\le \int_X\|f(x)\|\,d\mu(x)
$$
where $f \colon X \to \mathbb R^n$ is $\mu$-measurable.
Of course you do not use "complex exponent" to do it.